# Creación de vistas en migraciones Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

A veces requerimos crear [vistas (SQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) de las tablas de la base de datos por diversos motivos. En la [documentación sobre migraciones de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations) no especifica nada respeto de vistas SQL. Pero sería bueno a la hora de correr migraciones, poder crear las vistas también con las migraciones, de ahí la pregunta:

**¿Cómo podemos crear vistas en la bade de datos con las migraciones en laravel?**

Supongamos el siguiente ejemplo básico extraído de la documentación de MySQL sobre las vistas

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (qty INT, price INT);
mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, 50);
mysql> CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;
mysql> SELECT * FROM v;
+------+-------+-------+
| qty  | price | value |
+------+-------+-------+
|    3 |    50 |   150 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

La vista en cuestión:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;
```

---

Version laravel preferible >= 5.6

SGBD = MySQL >= 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma sería utilizar el facade `DB` con el método `statement` para la creación de la vista desde una migración.

Crear la migración   con el nombre que desee, después de crear las tablas que estarán involucradas , si no lanzará error al ejecutar la migración.

```
php artisan make:migrate create_view_select_table
```

Y en la migración ejecutar la `query` de creación de la vista directamente

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;");
}

public function down()
{
    DB::statement("DROP VIEW v");
}
```

Desde el controlador o alguna otra parte que desee obtener el resultado de la vista , también utilizaría el facade `DB`

```
DB::select('select * from v');
```

Answer (score 1):

A mi me gusta más así, porque cuando se hace un reset no da error.

```
    public function up()
{
    DB::statement("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS SELECT SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;");
}


public function down()
{
    DB::statement("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v;");
}
```